# RPC interface not working?

Tags: rpc

I am following the steps in this tutorial:

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart

and everything has worked so far. However, when I try this:

"Also go to this address in the browser to check that RPC interface is working: http://localhost:8888/v1/chain/get_info "

I get no output at all. My installation is on Ubuntu.

Comment: Does `$ cleos get info` work after you complete the rest of the steps on the page?

Comment: @larsemanse do you want to write an answer for the steps you did or shall I delete this question?

Comment: `cleos get info` working. But http://localhost:8888/v1/chain/get_info and `curl http://localhost:8888/v1/chain/get_info` doesn't work. How to fix it? I use docker.

Comment: maybe it's not running on localhost:8888?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because `localhost` is not relaying the browser's request to the docker container.

Run `docker-machine ip default` to get the ip for your docker container.

```
$ docker-machine ip default
192.XXX.XX.XXX
```

Now try accessing the RPC interface from your browser using the returned ip address:

```
http://192.XXX.XX.XXX:8888/v1/chain/get_info
```

You should receive a json response similar to what was shown in the docs:

```
{
    "server_version": "0961a560",
    "chain_id": "cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f",
    "head_block_num": 13780,
    "last_irreversible_block_num": 13779,
    "last_irreversible_block_id": "000035d36e1ca29ba378081c574ab3b5ab4214ba29754dd42b512690a9f03e80",
    "head_block_id": "000035d4165c9225d7a04822d142fbcb15f997a6f2571dc7bae8437dea782205",
    "head_block_time": "2018-05-23T16:30:54",
    "head_block_producer": "eosio",
    "virtual_block_cpu_limit": 100000000,
    "virtual_block_net_limit": 1048576000,
    "block_cpu_limit": 99900,
    "block_net_limit": 1048576
}
```

This worked for me, lmk if you have any issues.  I'm also new to docker, so edits to correct my terminology above are appreciated.

Comment: I did not find docker-machine, but I ran "docker inspect eosio" and a load of info was listed, including the correct ip adress 0.0.0.0:8888. I used that adress in my browser: http://0.0.0.0:8888/v1/chain/get_info and the info I was looking for got listed.

Comment: @larsemanse Its great that billbit could solve your problem. You should click "Accept answer" next to his answer so that others know that this solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

$ cleos get info

to check if the RPC interface is working.

Comment: That's not to check if RPC is working or not. It is to check whether your nodeos is working or not. To check RPC thing, you need to test HTTP API.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate:

```
nodeos --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888 // Mind No spaces around =
```

This worked for me. All other try with `config.ini` didn't work